# WebAssembly access to system resources

Tags: webassembly

Will WebAssembly ever have direct access to WEB APIs without having to call JavaScript functions?
If so, when will that happen? (Timeframe).
(I regard JavaScript as an abomination, and I want to get up to writing superfast web apps without having to use it altogether).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the WebAPIs will never be directly exposed to the WebAssembly virtual machine. It is designed to be a low level machine that is hosted within an environment, most typically the web browser, but also node, and potentially others in the future.

The mechanics of exposing the host environment to a WebAssembly will get easier in future with the host binding spec, but the general principle will not change.

However, in the future, I’m sure others will write the required ‘glue code’ so that you don’t have to touch JavaScript!